# Two random numbers to create range in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to make 2 PHP random numbers for number range.
So for example i want numbers from 100 to 300 with range 20.
And PHP will give you:
**100-120** or
**101-121**,
**110-130** and so on...

I tried this:

```
while (true) { 
$x = rand(100,300);  
$y = rand(100,300);

 if($x - $y == 20){
  echo 'from ' . $x . ' to' . $y;
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just `$x = rand(100, 280); $y = $x + 20;`?

Comment: Yes, good point. If it's easy to do, why I always make it harder :D

Comment: If Nick gave a working answer, please add it as answer (not a comment) and mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $from = rand(100, 280);
  $to = $x + 20;
```

For my array:

```
array_slice($array, $from, $to);
```